# Сумма индексов массива между минимальным и максимальным элементом

Tags: c#

В последней строке *х *=i;* мне показывает что переменная *i* неизвестна, не понимаю из-за чего это и как исправить.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Arrays1DConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.Write("Количество элементов в массиве: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double[] elems = new double[n];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Случайно сгенерированный одномерный массив: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                elems[i] = rnd.NextDouble() * 78.4 - 27.8;
                elems[i] = Math.Round(elems[i], 1);
                Console.Write($"{elems[i]} ");
            }
            double MaxValue = elems.Max<double>();
            double MinValue = elems.Min<double>();
            double IndexMin = Array.IndexOf(elems, MinValue);
            double IndexMax = Array.IndexOf(elems, MaxValue);
            double x = 0;
            for (double i = IndexMin + 1; i < IndexMax; i++) ;
            {
                x *= i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i++) ;` что видите?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я в шоке, у меня всегда такие глупые ошибки, спасибо!